# XSLT - Check if pattern exists in an element string

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following element as part of a larger XML

```
<MT N="NonEnglishAbstract" V="[DE] Deutsch Abstract text [FR] French Abstract text"/>
```

I need to do some formatting of the value in `@V` attribute, only if it contains anything like [DE], [FR] or any two capital letters representing a country code within square brackets.

If no such pattern exist, I need to simply write the value of `@V` without any formatting.

I can use an XSLT 2.0 solution

I was hoping that I could use the matches() function something like

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="matches(@V,'\[([A-Z]{{2}})\]([^\[]+'">
//Do something
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Are `<MT` your element tags your matching in?

Comment: @hwnd:yes, that is right.

Comment: Not sure why you are doubling your curly braces, when the test attribute is not an AVT? Also, what is the purpose of the `(` after the `\]`? You don't really want to match a literal paren, do you?

Comment: @LarsH: I must admit, I got the expression from the answer to one of my other question on SO, which involves `<xsl:analyze-string select="@V" regex="\[([A-Z]{{2}})\]([^\[]+)">.` I tried to use the same with the test attribute, and was getting a compile error. I suppose the expression in Ken's answer below is better anyway.

Comment: OK. I guess the `(` was supposed to be part of a capture group, rather than a literal paren; but you got a compile error because the matching paren was missing in the code posted above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all you need is:

```
matches(@V,'\[[A-Z][A-Z]\]')
```

You don't have to match the entire string to get a `true()` ... I tell my students to write as short a reg-ex as possible.

Comment: @Ken: Many thanks. This works very well. I accept this as the answer since I specifically asked for XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have not posted anything about what you have tried. How about looking up translate function and translating the strings capital letters to something like "X". Then test that string result for the existence of [XX]. That alone would tell you whether you need to process it.

```
<xsl:variable name="result">
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(@V,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then use that result and then test:

```
 contains($result, "[XX]")
```

No regex required, pure XSL 1.1

Comment: Many thanks. I could use that. I have updated the question with what I had in mind. Is it possible to use the matches function, with a one-liner?

Comment: contains(---put translate here --,'[XX]])
I always practice using variables in case you need them later and making things much easier to debug. If you don't want the variable, inject the whole translate() function into the contains()

Comment: Use of XSLT 1.1 is deprecated to the extent that it should be absolutely prohibited.  I advise my students *never* (ever!) to use XSLT 1.1. The justification is that the W3C in August 2001 *formally* halted any support for XSLT 1.1 and recommends that XSLT 2.0 be used. This is documented officially in http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-xslt11-20010824/ in the notice in the "Status of this Document" at the beginning.  Some of my students come to class using XSLT 1.1 in their production work and I warn them they shouldn't be:  there only ever was one vendor and the product isn't supported anymore.

Comment: Totally agreed Ken, but there is nothing 1.1 *only* about it. It works with 2.0 *and* 1.1. It is a perfect alternative for someone that does not know or wish to learn Regex.

Comment: Forgive me, I wasn't critiquing the answer, I was only addressing the issue of people citing 1.1 perhaps without knowing that 1.1 should never be used. And, anyway, your approach works with XSLT 1.0.